# ColdFusion error after hosting transfer

Tags: windows, coldfusion, mssqlft

I recently moved a ColdFusion site from one domain to the other with no issue (practically) besides one which I am having some trouble figuring out.  I am a LAMP developer / designer and CF is a bit foreign to me so pardon my ignorance.

The site is working properly except for the store component, I am getting the following error "The .cart.models.store name is not a valid component or interface name.Component and interface names cannot be empty and cannot start or end with a period.".  The only piece of code that I have changed throughout this process has been the config.ini, I changed the `vmap=SitenameDev` to `vmap=` as the notes in this file recommneded to do if the directory housing the site was the webroot directory.

Any insight on this error or common issues when transferring will be greatly appreciated, as always.

JN

Comment: It will be very helpful if you'll show the chunk of code throwing error and describe a bit your server configuration.

Comment: And please, ColdFusion (one word) is a software product, cold fusion is a physical process http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_fusion Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the config.ini is something specific to the app you're dealing not a ColdFusion convention of any sort. Most likely the "vmap" entry therein means "virtual mapping". Its value is probably being used to resolve a path to an object (i.e. [value of vmap] + ".cart.models.store". With it empty, you're getting an error because ColdFusion wants its paths to not start with a period, and is unable to resolve the location of the file its looking for to create an object.

So previously this path was "SitenameDev.cart.models.store". What you need to do is figure out what directory houses the "cart\models\store" hierarchy. Then in the ColdFusion administrator setup a mapping to its parent directory - that is an alias to a physical directory that ColdFusion recognizes. Then whatever alias you choose should be set as the "vmap" value in the config.ini file.